# Windows10 permission about exe

Tags: permissions, windows-10

I am studying C with Code:Blocks on Windows 10. But I am suffering from a permission problem. 
The problem is that I can not run an exe created using codeblocks.(The problem occurs on not only codeblocks but also any other IDE)
If I find the .exe file in Windows Explorer and run it separately, I got a message that you do not have permission. 
Also I can't see anything on the Security tab of the file properties. So I can't change anything about permission of the exe file. How can I run an exe file created myslef?? Please help me.

Comment: Where are you saving the exe files? Is that a shared comouter?

Comment: I saved it on desktop folder...

Comment: And what if you try other folder? Especially, try to create new folder at the root of your main drive and save there. Desktop along with other user specific folders are usually encrypted and sometimes can lead to permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the exe and click on run as administrator

Comment: Oh :( https://superuser.com/questions/364586/why-cant-exe-file-be-run-due-to-permission-issues this might help you